# Heroku: not building with latest version of code

Tags: heroku, node.js, git, github

I'm evaluating Heroku for hosting my Node.js api server, and I'm running into an unexpected issue. The code in the actual pushed branch isn't executed.

Whether I'm pulling code from github, or using git push heroku, the following code in index.js isn't executed:

```
  console.log('Environment PORT set to ', envOpenPort);

  httpServer.listen(httpPort, () => {
    console.log(`CHANGED API server http listening on ${httpPort}`);
  });
```

Regardless of what I do, I get the log output from old versions:

2021-09-29T17:01:51.171640+00:00 app[web.1]: API server http listening on 8082

What I've tried:

- Deleting the app and starting from scratch
- Verifying the git branch id is correct
- Verifying the code in the branch has the line above
- Purging the build cache with "heroku builds:cache:purge -a alwaystest"
- Pushing to github with "git push -f", and then triggering manual build from admin window
- Push to Heroku with "git push heroku" or "git push -f heroku". In both cases it takes a very long time to upload. Like it isn't doing the deltas but the whole branch each time. The push to github finishes in a fraction of the time.

This is a monorepo, and I have the following setup in the root package.json

root package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "yarn workspaces foreach -pt --exclude xxx_frontend --exclude root run build",
    "build:all": "yarn workspaces foreach -pt run build",
    "build:all-server-force": "yarn workspaces foreach -pt --exclude xxx_frontend --exclude root run build:force",
    "build:force": "tsc -b --force tsconfig.json",
    "start": "yarn workspace api dev"
  },
```

API package.json

```
    "build": "tsc -b tsconfig.json",
    "build:force": "tsc -b --force tsconfig.json",
    "watch-ts": "tsc -b tsconfig.json -w",
    "dev": "nodemon ./dist/index.js"
  },
```

My understanding is that Heroku will run the build script and then the start script.

I'm at my wit's end. What could be going on here?

EDIT: Here is my .gitignore

```
node_modules/

*.log

.yarn/
.yarn/*
!.yarn/patches
!.yarn/releases
!.yarn/plugins
!.yarn/sdks
!.yarn/versions
.pnp.*
```

EDIT 2. Top of build log after adding NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false

```
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       USE_YARN_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
        !     You don't need to specify Yarn engine. Heroku will install the latest Yarn 1.x, so that per project version can be used. More information here: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install#global-install
              https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support
       
       engines.node (package.json):  ^16.7.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   ^7.21.0
       engines.yarn (package.json):  unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version ^16.7.0...
       Downloading and installing node 16.10.0...
       Bootstrapping npm ^7.21.0 (replacing 7.24.0)...
       npm ^7.21.0 installed
       Resolving yarn version 1.22.x...
       Downloading and installing yarn (1.22.13)
       Using yarn 3.0.1
       
-----> Restoring cache
       Caching has been disabled because NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
```

This message is pretty weird since i recently added the npm version for example:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "^16.7.0",
    "yarn": "^3.0.1",
    "npm": "^7.21.0"
  },
```

Comment: have you tried setting `NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false`

Comment: also, mind sharing your gitignore file? assuming you aren't commiting your node_modules folder

Comment: Thanks glls. I added the .gitignore in the post.

Comment: did you try `NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false`

Comment: Yes, I tried NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false. Still same result.